# Run consecutive update() queries on Django Model

Tags: django

Just a question to better comprehend Django and its models.

I want to update a big number of instances in a queryset named **files**

But I want to update two fields. One for all, and one for some. I tried this:

```
files.filter(date_first_notified__isnull=True).update(date_first_notified=timezone.now())
files.update(date_notified=timezone.now())
```

It only executes the first one, also when I turn them around. Can I not run two, or more, update queries on one queryset?

P.S. It might be obvious, but I want to create a better version of:

```
for f in files:
    f.date_notified = timezone.now()
    if f.date_first_notified__isnull:
        f.date_first_notified = timezone.now()
        f.save()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't solve your update problem - but you can avoid the need for this update by setting `date_first_notified` as [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add), and `date_notified` as `auto_now`.

Comment: Thanks @BurhanKhalid,  but date_first_notified is not filled at creation, so that doesn't work either. But clever solution. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
files.all().update(date_notified=timezone.now())
```

?

Comment: Thanks, didn't try, but have tried now, doesn't work. ;-( The first one does, but then the second one has no impact/result.

Comment: Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it would be good idea to make some debug output. I.e. make prints of ```files.filter(...)``` content, the same content after ```update```, and then the same for ```files.all()```.